# Personal finance application for Mac/iOS

Tags: osx, ios, finance

I'm looking for a personal finance application. I've tried [Squirrel](http://squirrelapp.com) and [MoneyWiz](http://www.moneywizapp.com), and they both have features I want, as well as flaws that make them nearly unusable for me. What I absolutely need (apart from the basics such as adding transactions into multiple accounts and tags/categories):

- Sync between a Mac App (native) and an iOS App (MoneyWiz does this beautifully, Squirrel's so called sync never seems to work)
- Scheduled transactions which show a prognosis for the balance in my account for the rest of the month or so (Like Squirrel does, MoneyWiz's "forecasting" is laughable)
- Import of a custom CSV file with transactions, where the app finds duplicates that have already been entered, and can categorize/tag transactions automatically.
- Support for multiple currencies (MoneyWiz is really good here, Squirrel almost adequate)
- A UI that doesn't require 4 clicks per scheduled transaction to pay them in advance (I.E. when I've scheduled them into my online bank). Squirrel is great here, MoneyWiz drives me up the wall.

Basically, I guess I want Squirrel, but with a sync that works and better currency support.

Comment: Squirrel's sync works fine for me—If Squirrel is so close to what you desire, maybe try looking into fixing Squirrel's sync as opposed to finding a new app?

Comment: @GeorgeGarside How large is your squirrel database? I would love to get it to work, but nothing ever shows up when I open the iOS app and enable iCloud sync.

Comment: It has a few hundred transactions and I've gradually built up to this, letting it sync often. Have you tried a new database?

Comment: @GeorgeGarside Mine has well over 3000 transactions spread across several accounts. I've used it since 2010. I'll try a new database and see if that helps.

Comment: @GeorgeGarside Well, after 2 hours of trying I finally have a new database that seems to sync between my iPhone and my Mac. My history is gone, and I have to enter all my import rules, categories, tags and scheduled transactions again, but perhaps a trim was good. I did stumble upon wanting a scheduled transaction in another currency than my own, which Squirrel doesn't seem to do well, so I'll leave the question up.